# Should autoencoders be symmetric?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, symmetric

I always find myself wanting to make the decoder side of an autoencoder as symmetric as possible with respect to the encoder side, because it feels like an "elegant" design decision.  But I suspect that it's not optimal.  And I'm not finding any direct discussions of this topic via google.

In most of mathematics, complex functions tend to have even more complex inverses. With respect to CNNs, convolutions are not strictly invertible, so it seems like the Conv2DTranspose operations could benefit from a higher complexity and parameter count to approximate it better.  I'm curious if anyone has direct experience studying this, or if there are conventions for "optimizing" the decoder side of an autoencoder (or maybe it's the encoder side needs more parameters...?).

My first inclination is to just double some numbers on the decoder side to give it twice as many parameters. But maybe including extra layers is better, since it more significantly increases the complexity of functions it can approximate.  Or maybe none of this is theoretically relevant.

Here's an almost perfectly-symmetric example network, that can be used as a reference point.  Obviously I could experiment with it to come up with ideas, but I'm more interested in the general theory and if there's any established ideas on the topic (and not just for CNNs, but all types of autoencoders).

### Encoder:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 48, 48, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 32)        2432      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 12, 12, 64)        32832     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 6, 6, 128)         73856     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 4608)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 256)               1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,305,472
```

### Decoder:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 64)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 256)               16640     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 4608)              1184256   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 6, 6, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 12, 12, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 24, 24, 32)        32800     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 48, 48, 3)         2403      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,309,891
```

For reference, the above computation graph was produced with the following code:

```
latent_size = 64

# Encoder
enc_input = L.Input(shape=(48, 48, 3))
enc0 = L.Conv2D(filters= 32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc_input)
enc1 = L.Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc0)
enc2 = L.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc1)

enc_flat = L.Flatten()(enc2)
enc_dense = L.Dense(256, activation='tanh')(enc_flat)
enc_out = L.Dense(latent_size, activation='linear')(enc_dense)
encoder = keras.Model(inputs=enc_input, outputs=enc_out, name='Encoder')

# Decoder
dec_input = L.Input(shape=(latent_size,))
dec_dense1 = L.Dense(256, activation='tanh')(dec_input)
dec_dense2 = L.Dense(6*6*128, activation='relu')(dec_dense1)
dec_reshape = L.Reshape((6,6,128))(dec_dense2)
dec2 = L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(dec_reshape)
dec1 = L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(dec2)
dec0 = L.Conv2DTranspose(filters= 3, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='linear')(dec1)
decoder = keras.Model(inputs=dec_input, outputs=dec0, name='Decoder')

encoder.summary()
decoder.summary()
```

Comment: Interesting question, but unfortunately off-topic since it's not related to programming; it's more of a conceptual question. It's also quite broad, so it would probably be a better fit for something like Quora or reddit.

Comment: A similar question with answers over at [data science stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23739/why-are-autoencoders-for-dimension-reduction-symmetrical)